# How to bound the biggest eigenvalue of $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_ix_i^T$?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

My question is to bound the biggest eigenvalue of $A=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_ix_i^T$, where $x_i\in\mathbb{R}^d$ is a column vector.

My idea is, to bound the biggest eigenvalue of $A$, i.e. $\|A\|_2$. I can bound $\|A\|_F$. However, it seems this is a rough solution, since I did not make use the special structure of matrix $A$, i.e. $A=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_ix_i^T$. The other way is that if we can explicitly represent   $\|A\|_2$ using $x_i$, we can also get a better solution, but I can not explicitly represent   $\|A\|_2$ using $x_i$.

Could you please help me？

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this helps.

Note that $A$ is symmetric positive semidefinite. The
biggest eigenvalue will be
$\max_{\|v\|=1} \langle v , Av\rangle $.
Since $\langle v , Av\rangle = \sum_k (x_k^T v)^2$, we can let
$X=\begin{bmatrix} x_1^T \\ \vdots \\ x_n^T \end{bmatrix}$ and then we have
$\langle v , Av\rangle = \| X v \|^2$ and so
$\|A\| = \|X\|^2$.